# How to fix declaration or statement expected error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, append

I want to append table row with dynamic drop down list but get error declaration or syntax error in jquery code. how to fix it?

```
$(".addtable").click(function () {
    debugger;
     $("#fields tbody").append("<tr><td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MedID, ViewBag.MedicineList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Category", id = "manfac", required = "required" })</td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name=" Quantity" required></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addtable">Add More</button><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>");

});
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You are adding server-side markup via client-side javascript. This is not how things work: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429/728795

Comment: declaration or syntax error.

Comment: Also show me uncaught syntax error ) is missing during debugging.

Comment: Well, if that script is not going though a pre-processor first to convert it to plain html, you're going to have issues there.  And even then, your plain part has unescaped double quotes that conflict with your string delimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this approach in a dummy project, I've discovered two issues:

1. You need to wrap your string with single-quotes instead of double-quotes, ie, change .append("...") to .append('...') .
2. Html.DropDownListFor() produces a string that has a newline character, which causes a line break in the javascript string, which throws a syntax error. So you need to do something like:
   `.append('@(Html.Raw(Html.DropDownListFor(...).ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")))')` , which looks really ugly, but it works in my dummy project.`

So try:

```
$(".addtable").click(function () {
debugger;
 $("#fields tbody").append('<tr><td>@(Html.Raw(Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MedID, ViewBag.MedicineList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Category", id = "manfac", required = "required" }).ToString().Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "")))</td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name=" Quantity" required></td><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addtable">Add More</button><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary remCF">Remove</a></td></tr>');
});
```